# Firefox css spinner animation rendering issue

Tags: html, css, firefox, rendering

A spinner I want to use on my site looks **bad** on Firefox (48.0.2).

[Comparison between Firefox and Chrome (imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUZUH.png)

[See the spinner live](http://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/) (Third spinner)

Is there a fix for this rendering issue?

Slowing the animation down didn't help so I'm turning to you guys (:D) and I don't think there is a fix for this yet on stackoverflow.

Here is code demonstrating the problematic spinner:

```css
body {
  background: #0dc5c1;
}
.loader {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  width: 11em;
  height: 11em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ffffff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 42%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 42%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 42%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 42%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 42%);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: load3 1.4s infinite linear;
  animation: load3 1.4s infinite linear;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
.loader:before {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 100% 0 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
}
.loader:after {
  background: #0dc5c1;
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes load3 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes load3 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">Loading...</div>
```

*Tested on Firefox, Chrome, Edge and IE(11). Only Firefox has problems.*

Comment: I think the only viable solution would be to use an image and rotate it instead of relying on the browser's CSS rendering of shapes, but even that has its own potential issues.

Comment: @Quantastical that's pretty good idea at least for now. I was too fixated on it being css/html shape that it being image didn't occur to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: #0dc5c1;
}
.loader {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  /*text-indent: -9999em;*/
  width: 11em;
  height: 11em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ffffff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 42%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 42%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 42%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 42%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 42%);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: load 1.4s infinite linear;
  animation: load 1.4s infinite linear;
/*   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);*/
}
.loader:before {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 100% 0 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
}
.loader:after {
  background: #0dc5c1;
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes load {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes load {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader"></div>
```